# keepalive parameter setting in openldap for consumer doesnot work

Tags: ldap, openldap, tcp

I unplugged network cable of My OpenLDAP *syncrepl* producer, added new users but it never synchronizes.
with the consumer. Consumer never sends the keep alive signals

I am using 2.4.39 version of OpenLDAP on windows machine

this is my consumer setting

```
olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=002 provider=ldap://ipaddress:389 bindmethod=sasl timeou
t=0 network-timeout=0 saslmech=external keepalive=1:1:10 starttls=critical tl
s_cert="CN=Consumer3" tls_cacert="CN=TestCA" tls_reqcert=demand
tls_cipher_suite=HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2 filter="(objectclass=*)" searchbase="dc=something,dc=com"  scope=sub attrs="*,+" schemachecking=off type=refreshAndPersist retry="60 +"
```

if I make fresh setup of consumer & provider, it works & everything gets replicated properly.

In the earlier version of OpenLDAP it was based on system setting like I used to get keepalive every 2 hours.
What is the minimum value to be set for keepalive parameter in syncrepl?
Can you please tell me do I need to make any changes on consumer side or provider ?

Comment: From the [*man page*](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapd.conf): "Only some systems support the customization of these values; the keepalive parameter is ignored otherwise, and system-wide settings are used.".

Comment: Thanks for the response, is it customizable in windows? if not what can I do make the keepalive parameter configurable in windows?